# JSONP callback not working from this cinema url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to create a successfull jsonp call to this url:
http://ws.cineplanet.cl:3080/sistemas/wscp?callback=?&florida_cartelera_fechas_horas

The strange thing is, when I use another url the callback works fine. Like this one: http://www.cinemark.cl/movies.json?callback=?
So it must be something server sided. But does anyone have a clue what it could be? I spend lot's of hours trying to make this work..  :(

Thanks in advance. This is the code that I used:

```
var jqxhr1 = $.ajax({
   url: "http://ws.cineplanet.cl:3080/sistemas/wscp?callback=?&florida_cartelera_fechas_horas", //this one does not work
   // url: "http://www.cinemark.cl/movies.json?callback=?", //this one works
   dataType: 'jsonp'
});

$.when(jqxhr1).done(function (jqxhr1) {
  console.log(jqxhr1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is server side.

It looks like that the http://ws.cineplanet.cl:3080/sistemas/wscp address doesn't support JSONP response.

If you check the address that works:

http://www.cinemark.cl/movies.json?callback=myCallback

You can see that the response JSON is wrapped in the myCallback function.

This doesn't seem to happen with the other URL:

http://ws.cineplanet.cl:3080/sistemas/wscp?florida_cartelera_fechas_horas&callback=myCallback

Some reading about JSONP:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Thank you for your reply! For now I will use php to convert it to json with file_get_contents and json_decode